# Collection custom reordering

Tags: .net, collections

I have collection of items and every of them has `int TypeId` property. I need to reorder items in this collection (or get new), where items are ordered so first all items with `TypeId = 3`, then with `TypeId = 1` and then `TypeId = 2`.
My solution is:

```
var result = new List<A>();
result.AddRange(source.Where(i => i.TypeId == 3));
result.AddRange(source.Where(i => i.TypeId == 1));
result.AddRange(source.Where(i => i.TypeId == 2));
```

I wonder, is there any another quick solution without multiple iterating over the `source` collection (may be some LINQ trick)?

Comment: What type of collection is your list? Some collection classes have in-built sorting functions which can be quite fast. Normally QuickSort is the preferred method, although (depending on how quick the Where functions is) this method does look quite efficient.

Comment: @Nick Udell: Here is a trick to sort by field which natural order no the same as should be used whilst sorting. So I believe this is not a task for standard sorting algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just create an order sequence array and use it in the OrderBy statement by simply asking for the index. Here is the pseudo logic (I can't remember if IndexOf is available with native array, but if not just use another collection type)

```
  int[] order = new int[] { 3, 1, 2};
  source.OrderBy(i => Array.IndexOf(order, i.TypeId));
```

-- EDITED the example based on comment from Luke so that it will compile correctly

Comment: +1, But you need to use the static `Array.IndexOf(order, i.TypeId)` rather than `order.IndexOf(i.TypeId)`.

Comment: Great for adding that. I will edit the answer so that it is more accurate

Comment: And if you wanted an in-place sort, rather than returning a new sequence: `source.Sort((x, y) => Array.IndexOf(order, x.TypeId).CompareTo(Array.IndexOf(order, y.TypeId)));`